# How can I get the value from the json I get through XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How can I get the url, title and img from the json I get through XMLHttpRequest?

```
   const base_url = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3"

function random(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
}

function sendRequest(meyhod,base_url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var id = random();

request.open('GET', `${base_url}/anime/${id}`);
request.responseType = 'json'
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
      if(this.status !== 200){
          return testjs();
      }
      else{
        request.onload = () =>{
        resolve(request.response)
    }}
  }
};
request.send();
})
}

function testjs(){
    sendRequest('GET', base_url)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(animepost)
}
function animepost(data){
    console.log(data.image_url)
    console.log(data.title)
    console.log(data.url)

}
```

Perhaps I messed up the queries somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you pass to your sendRequest are very weird.

```
function sendRequest(meyhod,base_url){
```

You are not using methode plus you only you use the 'GET' method and baseUrl is accessible within the function.
You should be passing the id like this

```
function sendRequest(id){
```

that you are using here

```
request.open('GET', `${base_url}/anime/${id}`);\
```

and your testjs should look somthing like this

```
function testjs(){
    sendRequest(theIdYouWantToFetch)
```